# loop numbers down and up and not using recursion in python

Tags: python, for-loop, numbers, integer, bounce

I have a small problem with my code. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I can get it to work with two for loops. But in the exercise it says that i only can use one loop to get the result.
The code is supposed to execute this:

bounce2(4):

- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

What I have come up with:

```
def bounce2(n):
    for x in range(n,-1,-1):
    print(x)
```

Which prints out 4,3,2,1,0
But now i dont know what to do..
I have tried different if statements such as:

```
def bounce2(n):
   for x in range(n,-1,-1):
   print(x)
   if n == 0:
   x = x + 1
   print(x)
```

But they only print one integer because they are out of the loop.
Same thing goes if i try to make the if-statement inside the loop, then it prints out something like 433221100. I dont know how to get the numbers to switch places. The print statement should also be an integer  and not a string. So i can't use replaced.

Really need help to figure out the logic. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: you need to loop `2*n+1` times, to print the lines.

Comment: Where am i suppose to put them?
after the if statement where x = x + 1 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I believe to be a pretty elegant solution:

```
def bounce(n):
    for x in range(-n, n+1):
        print(abs(x))
```

Our loop goes from the negative of n to the positive of n, printing the absolute value.

Comment: Yeah was very east and neat. Thank you for the solution. I tried earlier:
 for x in range(n,-n-1,-1):
  print(abs(x))
 but didnt know I could use the abs() function to get the negative integers to turn positive :)

Answer (score 3):

So, a little bit of my thought process before showing you the code. Clearly there are nine lines, or more generally `n * 2 + 1` lines. Because we need to count down to 0 and back up. That's how many times you need to call print.

Now, if you add line numbers to the expected output and think of it as a table describing a function `f(i, n)` where `i` is the line number, and `n` is the starting and ending value. what is `f`? Can you write down the formula? e.g.

```
i f(i, 4)
0  4
1  3
2  2
3  1
4  0
5  1
6  2
7  3
8  4
```

We can write down the basic structure of the code, we still don't know what `f` look like but assume we have it:

```
for i in range(2*n+1):
    print f(i)
```

And, what is `f`? Now you need to be a little creative and maybe experiment a bit. What I did was to try basic arithmetic combinations of `i` and `n` to match `f(i, n)`, and I quickly noticed that `n - i` works until we reach the second half of the output, which only differs by a `-` sign.

```
i f(i, 4) n - i
0  4       4
1  3       3
2  2       2
3  1       1
4  0       0
5  1       -1
6  2       -2
7  3       -3
8  4       -4
```

Soooo, take the absolute value of `n - i` or `i - n`, whatever.

```
def f(i, n):
    return abs(n-i)
```

Comment: thank you **@xiaofeng.li** this made things a little more clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to count `n` times downwards, and another `n` times upwards, and `1` comes from counting `0`, instead of actually counting downwards and then upwards in two separate loops, we can use one loop to count upwards `2 * n + 1` times, which effectively is like counting towards `n` and then bouncing off `n`, so we can simply calculate the "distance" to `n` instead, which is the absolute value of `n - x`:

```
def bounce2(n):
    for x in range(2 * n + 1):
        print(abs(n - x))
```

so that `bounce2(4)` would output:

```
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im still a little confused how  u came up with 2 * n + 1.
I know that it prints out 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 if u dont use the abs(n-x)) and only print out the x. How do you know it should be abs(n - x))?

Comment: `2 * n` comes from the fact that you need to count `n` times downwards, and another `n` times upwards, and `1` comes from counting `0`. So instead of actually counting downwards and then upwards in two separate loops, we can use one loop to count upwards `2 * n + 1` times, which effectively is like counting towards `n` and then bouncing off `n`, so we can simply calculate the "distance" to `n` instead, which `abs(n - x)` returns.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple solution will be:

```
for i in range(n, -(n+1), -1):
    print(abs(i))
```

this like mirroring numbers around some point.
in your case that point is zero and to have identical mirroring use `abs`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, have a list `l` with a element of `str(n)` iterate trough the range of `n` times 2, then check `x` is bigger than `n+2` if it is add 1 to `n`, otherwise subtract 1 from `n`, both cases append to `l`, then at the end, do `str.join` to join `'\n'` (newline) with `l`:

```
def bounce2(n):
   l=[str(n)]
   for x in range(n*2):
      if x>n+2:
         n+=1
         l.append(str(n))         
      else:
         n-=1
         l.append(str(n))
   return '\n'.join(l)
print(bounce2(4))
```

Output:

```
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can u explain how you where thinking when you wrote your code?

Comment: @teslagosu Edited mine